# Add a value to a column on a different row based on similarities in R

Tags: r

I have the following dataframe in R:

[image]

I am trying to make an extra column called "Opposition" which I would like to be the other team that has the same `Date`, `Venue` and inverse of the `Margin`. My expected output is:

[image]

Does anyone know how to achieve this in R? Im fairly new and cant quite work it out. Thanks!

Comment: We cannot copy data from an image. Add them in a reproducible format which is easier to copy. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could reverse the `Team A` value for each `Team`, `Date` and absolute value of `Margin`.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(Venue, Date, tmp = abs(Margin)) %>%
  mutate(Opposition = rev(`Team A`)) %>%
  select(-tmp) -> result

result
```

Comment: thanks! this worked, just had to add Venue instead of Team as the first argument in the group by, Thanks alot!

Comment: You are right about that. Updated the answer, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that your dataframe is named `dataset`, and then

```
dataset %>%
  left_join(dataset %>% mutate(Margin=-Margin) %>%
              rename(Opposition=`Team A`),
            by=c("Team A", "Date", "Venue")
  )
```

will do the trick.
Please note that `dplyr` package is required to utilize `mutate(), rename(), left_join()` functions, and `magrittr` package to utilize `%>%` pipe operator. You can import both packages at once by importing `tidyverse` package.

Comment: thanks, i tried the other option first and it worked! appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

Using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, Opposition := `Team A`[.N:1], .(Venue, Date, tmp = abs(Margin))]
```

Answer (score 0):

A base R option with `ave` + `rev` may help

```
transform(
  df,
  Opposition = ave(TeamA, Date, Venue, abs(Margin),FUN = rev)
)
```